# How can i use phone to phone call feature using sinch sdk

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I have implemented app to app calling & app to phone calling using but
How can i use phone to phone call feature using sinch sdk. I have seen this feature in REBTEL app as local call setting. i can not find any tutorial related to this on sinch official website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you rent a couple of phone numbers set up the callback url, 
on your server side you then prep the system so if you get a call on number A connect it to number B. There is a tutorial for it here 
https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/keep-users-phone-numbers-private-uber-x/

Comment: Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829185/can-not-get-headers-for-sinch-incoming-call-when-application-is-in-close-state-f ?

Comment: we can not  verify indonesia phone number using sinch android latest verification sdk V1.4.0.

Comment: @cjensen - we have seen your article on above link but what our requirement is that we don't have internet connection and we want to make a phone to phone call on desired end recipient without any interruption for the customer to dial the recipient number after custom assistant. So how to achieve that?